# How to insert a specific string between two words stored in a single variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to insert a string `"and"` between two words of a string stored in a variable.

How can I achieve this in Python?

E.g.

Input string or input variable:

```
location = 'Location-1 Location-2 '
```

Expected Output:

```
location = 'Location-1 and Location-2'
```

But I don't want to insert `"and"` if the variable has single value

```
location = 'Location-1 '
```

or

```
location = 'Location-2 '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the string `split()` and `join()` methods:

```py
location = 'Location-1 Location-2 '

location = ' and '.join(location.split())

print(repr(location))
```

Output:

```py
'Location-1 and Location-2'
```

`split()` splits a string into a list on a given delimiter, by default a whitespace. Since there is no string after the last whitespace, we also don't need to use `strip()`. `join()` joins a list of strings using the string the method is called on.